# "error": "instances is a plain list, but expecting list of objects as multiple input tensors required as per tensorinfo_map"}"

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvsIA.png)
[mycode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLmsZ.png)
I tried to load my saved keras model and converted it into model.tar.gz format and uploaded it to s3 bucket. i have deployed a tensorflowmodel and generated an enpoint, but have a problem to predicting with the endpoint, giving me the error saying the input format expected is not matched.
How do i overcome this error or how do i change it to the desired input format.
Tried a lot, no satisfuing solutions, please help out